# Check what the method of mocked object receives

Tags: scala, mockito

In my project, whenever a class produces some output, instead of doing `println` it calls `OutputStore.write`, which is a class and method I defined.

I am trying to test the output of another class so I mocked `OutputStore`. I want to see what parameters it receives to `OutputStore.write`.

```
val mockOutputStore = mock[OutputStore]
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
val argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(classOf[OutputStore])
verify(mockOutputStore).write(argument.capture())
assertEquals("some parameter", argument.getValue())
```

However, this doesn't compile as `verify` is not even recognized.

The signature of my test class is this:

```
class SomeUnitTestSet extends org.scalatest.FunSuite with MockitoSugar with PropertyChecks
```

Any idea how to check what parameters a mocked object's method receives?

Comment: verify is a static method of Mockito. In Java, it would have to be statically imported to be used like that instead of using Mockito.verify(). Since you're using assertEquals() instead of Assert.assertEquals(), you should be able to figure out how to do the same thing with verify() (I don't know Scala)

Comment: Also note that you don't need an ArgumentCaptor to do that. You can just use `verify(mockOutputStore).write("some parameter")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a translation of what @JBNizet suggested into a Scala code

Assuming you have your `OutputStore` class

```
class OutputStore {
  def write(msg: String) = {
    println(msg)
  }
}
```

and some `OutputStoreApiUser` class

```
class OutputStoreApiUser(val outputStore: OutputStore) {
  def foo(): Unit = {
    outputStore.write("some parameter")
    outputStore.write("some parameter2")
  }
}
```

Then your test might be something like this (in real life you probably @Inject `outputStore` but this is not relevant here):

```
import org.mockito.Mockito.verify // static import!
import org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar
import org.scalatest.prop.PropertyChecks

class SomeUnitTestSet extends org.scalatest.FunSuite with MockitoSugar with PropertyChecks {

  test("Capture calls"){
    val mockOutputStore = mock[OutputStore]
    val apiUser = new OutputStoreApiUser(mockOutputStore)
    apiUser.foo()
    verify(mockOutputStore).write("some parameter")
    verify(mockOutputStore).write("some parameter2")
  }

}
```

This one compiles and works for me as I would expect